# Lightning for Visualforce record delete not working

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-for-visualforce

VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" tabstyle="account" sidebar="false" extensions="testpagec">
<apex:form >
<apex:includeLightning />
<div id="lightning"/>
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accList}" var="a" id="list">
<apex:column value="{!a.Id}" />
<apex:column value="{!a.name}"/>
<apex:column id="blk">
    <script>
    var acc
        $Lightning.use("c:testpage", function() {
          $Lightning.createComponent("c:buttoncomp",
          {},
          "{!$Component.blk}",
          function(cmp) {
           acc=cmp;
          });
        });
    </script>
</apex:column>
<br/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>    
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

apex class:

```
public class testpagec{
    public List<account> accList {get;set;}
    public testpagec(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    accList = [Select id,Name from account limit 100];
    }
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Account deleteExpense(Account ac) {
    delete ac;
    return ac;
   }
}
```

lightning app:

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp"> 
 <aura:dependency resource="c:buttoncomp"/>
</aura:application>
lightning component:
<aura:component>
<aura:attribute name="acc" type="String" />
<ui:button aura:id="DelButton" label="Delete" press="{!c.delete}" />
</aura:component>
```

events:

```
<aura:event type="COMPONENT">
<aura:attribute name="ae" type="account"/>
</aura:event>
```

controller:

```
({
    delete : function(component, evt, helper) {
    var ac = component.get("v.acc");    
    var deleteEvent = component.getEvent("deleteaccevent");
    deleteEvent.setParams({ "ae": ac }).fire();
}
})
```

helper:

```
({
    deleteap : function(component, expense, callback) {
    // Call the Apex controller and update the view in the callback
    var action = component.get("c.deleteExpense");
    action.setParams({
        "ac": ac
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {

        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
})
```

I have created a lightning componenet button and exposing to vf page on list of account records.
If i click the delete it should delte a record in server.but it is not working. kinldy he;p me to resolve the issue.